# Error in gtkText() : could not find function "gtkText"

Tags: r, rgtk2

I installed R 3.4.4 version for Windows. I'm studying RGtk package but I can't to execute the instruction

```
gtkText()
```

Obviously, I installed the package:

```
install.packages("RGtk2", depen = T, type = "source")
library(RGtk2)
```

After the command

```
textx <- gtkText()
```

I obtain

```
Error in gtkText() : could not find function "gtkText"
```

Why?

Comment: [There seems to be no `gtkText()` in your package.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RGtk2/RGtk2.pdf)

Comment: Type `help(package="RGtk2")`.